# Force Method to be called after overloaded constructor is called from the Super-class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a unity3d project where I have an abstract object that I will be calling from other objects. I want all my subclasses to call a certain virtual method after they finish constructing. Essentially the base constructor will be called, then the overloaded constructor, and finally my method, but I want this behavior defined from the base object.

Comment: Could you please provide some sampe code which show your class-structure?

Comment: Use a factory to construct your objects, and have that factory call the desired virtual method.

Answer (score 1):

You can force your subclass to implement an abstract method called Initialize() and then choose the order of calls in your base class :

```
    public abstract class MyBaseClass
    {
        public abstract void Initialize();

        public MyBaseClass()
        {
            // Code of the constructor of the base class

            // Calling the subclass 
            Initialize();

            // Finally call the special method
            MySpecialMethod();
        }

        private void MySpecialMethod()
        {
            // Some code here
        }
    }

    public class MySubclass : MyBaseClass
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            // Some code here
        }
    }
```